# tan(x) from sin(x) and cos(x)

Tags: trigonometry

Given `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` can I determine the value of `tan(x)` without using tan itself (i.e: no `sin^-1(sin(x))` etc)?

Comment: I wonder how this question offended two users enough to downvote both answers. It's a somewhat curious thing to be ignorant of for someone who knows the trig functions in the first place -- but it's not as if this looks anything like a plausible homework question...

Comment: I was trying to see if there was an easy way to do an approximation of `tan(x)` using the double quadratic trick for `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` and I haven't done trigonometry in a while so I forgot. I don't see why there would need to be anymore context it seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:
$$ \tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} $$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$.